# JMeter: adding two numbers, one from function

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to get the current time in milliseconds and to add to it 5 minutes... Tried:

```
${__time + 1000 * 60 * 5}
```

Tried many more variations, none of them worked..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering myself, sharing it with you...

The solution here is to use:

```
{__longSum(${__time}, 900000)}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try this too.

`${__groovy(System.currentTimeMillis()+5*60*1000,)}`

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative that would work also similar to the groovy solution is:

```
${__jexl2(${__time}+900000)}
```